# Closed Sicilian Problem if Black Fianchettoes His Light-Squared Bishop

Tags: sicilian-defense, pawn-structure, center, closed-position

Help! Please.

After Bb7, I often play f4, followed by g4-g5 and h5. But the Bishop at b7 always gives me problems because it seems that my position after playing f4 will be too open after Black exchanges some pawns in the center and my kingside can be attacked easily.

I've been searching for several books but all books that I have seen so far on Amazon or chessbase.com only cover the variation where Black either fianchettoes at the kingside only or the variation where Black fianchettoes both Bishops. I am only interested in the variation where Black doesn't fianchetto in the kingside but fianchettoes in the queenside.

After the last move by Black. I am often confused where to put my a-Rook. When I push d4-d5 after few moves, my opponent often maneuver his Knight to c4 via a5, attacking my Queen and Bishop. Or in some cases, after playing f5, my opponent puts his Knight to e5 since it cannot be attacked by the f-pawn anymore. What is the common plan for White in this position? What should I do with Black's b7-Bishop?

```
[fen ""]

1. e4 c5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. g3 e6 4. Nge2 d6 5. Bg2 a6 6. O-O Qc7 7. d3 Be7 8. Be3 Nf6 9. h3 {Preventing Black from harrassing my Bishop} O-O 10. Qd2 b5 11. a3 Bb7
```

Comment: Why would you push d4-d5? If you try to break through on the kingside, you want the centre to be stable. Also: Qd2 is usually intended to support Bh6 in the line with g6+Bg7. In this line without Bg7 the queen might want to go to g4 or h5 in one move, after you pushed the kingside pawns.

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the biggest issues with the Closed Sicilian is that many players of the white pieces often feel that they should somehow be able to roll Black off of the board. However, if Black seeks active counterplay, such as the expansion on the Q-side with ...a6 and ...b5, then he is usually equal, if not slightly better.

Once the stereotypical moves of the closed Sicilian are made by white, the position is usually equal, and it's up to white to either outplay his opponent, or get dominated on the Q-side. Your line isn't a bad line, it's just that with the majority of your pieces located on the K-side, Black will usually have more than sufficient Q-side counterplay.

One of the reasons why many people play Open Sicilians is because it allows more variety on how you want to play the position, and often, which side of the board you want to play on. The closed Sicilian, in the manner that you played it, for the most part, only leaves you with one option. A K-side attack that can be negated with a few adjustments. Once Black counters that strategy, you are simply left with an even position where you may even have to relocate your pieces to the Q-side. Even more difficult to have to find a strategy for...at any given moment, Black will get in the move ...d5, followed by a possible ...f6 at some point as well. This position doesn't really hold any dangers for Black unless he grossly misplays it.